# C# I'm using string arrays, and I was hoping to use a "foreach" to Display a list of them

Tags: c#, arrays, if-statement, foreach

I believe that most of my code is correct for the most part aside from the foreach statement. I haven't been able to test it however due to the fact that the program isn't compiling.  I'd appreciate any and all help, even if my structure needs to change somewhat.

```
private static void PickScreen(Human myHuman)
    {
        var tries = 3;
        bool answer = false;
        string choice= "";

        string[] choices = new string[6];


        choices[0] = "Name";
        choices[1] = "Age";
        choices[2] = "Scar Type";
        choices[3] = "Weapon";
        choices[4] = "Hero Status";
        choices[5] = "Potions";

        DisplayNewScreenHeader();

        Console.WriteLine(" What screen would you like to go to?");
        Console.WriteLine();


        foreach (string i in choices)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" Screen Choice: {0}", choices[]);

        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(" Or you can type in " + "\"Default\"" + "to not have to do any of the query screens and have your character have default settings.");

        while(tries > 0)
        {
             Console.WriteLine(" Choice: ");
             choice = Console.ReadLine();

              if (choice.Equals("name", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                 {
                        DisplayGetHeroName(myHuman);
                    answer = true;
                 }
              else if (choice.Trim().Equals("age", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                 {
                        DisplayGetUsersAge(myHuman);
                    answer = true;
                 }
              else if (choice.Trim().Equals("Scar Type", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                        DisplayGetScar(myHuman);
                 answer = true;
             }
             else if (choice.Trim().Equals("weapon", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
             {
                        DisplayGetWeapon(myHuman);
                 answer = true;
             }
              else if (choice.Trim().Equals("Hero Status", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
             {
                        DisplayGetHeroStatus(myHuman);
                    answer = true;
             }
             else if (choice.Trim().Equals("Potions", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
             {
                        DisplayAddBackpackItems(myHuman);
                    answer = true;
             }
              else if (choice.Trim().Equals("Default", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
              {
                  Console.WriteLine(" Looks like you went with the lazy way.  Anyways go conquer basements, and become ruler of stuff!");
              }
             else 
             {
                 Console.WriteLine(" Dog gone it, yer Missed up a bit tad.");
                 Console.WriteLine();
                 Console.WriteLine(" Try again");
                 tries -= 1;
             }

        }

       if (answer == false)
         {
           DisplayNewScreenHeader();

           Console.WriteLine(" Since you're incompetent you no longer have the option to pick your query screens. They will simply go in order now.");
           DisplayGetHeroName(myHuman);
           DisplayGetUsersAge(myHuman);
           DisplayGetScar(myHuman);
           DisplayGetWeapon(myHuman);
           DisplayGetHeroStatus(myHuman);
           DisplayAddBackpackItems(myHuman);

           DisplayReturnPrompt();
         }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Within a `foreach` loop, your variable (in this case `i`) is set to each value in the enumeration as the loop continues.  You'll need to change:

```
foreach (string i in choices)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" Screen Choice: {0}", choices[]);

        }
```

To:

```
foreach (string i in choices)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" Screen Choice: {0}", i);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `foreach` loop should as below as `i` is actually one of the entries in `choices`

```
foreach (string i in choices)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" Screen Choice: {0}", i);

    }
```

As `foreach` iterates through your array, `i` will have the values:

```
choices[1]
choices[2]
choices[3]
.......
etc
```

Comment: Thank you, I am just starting out so I'm not very familiar with a lot of things.  And I don't understand what you said
 "Unlike a for loop, the variable i is iteratively populated with values inside the choices array." 
But your fix worked. Is it possible for you to explain what you just did in maybe non so technical terms?

Comment: Tried to clarify my answer

Answer (score 0):

Change

Console.WriteLine(" Screen Choice: {0}", choices[]);

To

Console.WriteLine(" Screen Choice: {0}", i);